# visualizing the tomcat server output with openshift

Tags: tomcat7, openshift

I just started using openshift with tomcat 7, 
and i was wondering if you could view the tomcat server output, like the "Apache tomcat" window in netbeans, where u can use the  `System.out.println();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Found the answer:
https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202328880

it's at `/app-root/logs`

Comment: Just for clarification, the full path is:
/var/lib/openshift/<your-id>/app-root/logs

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has a catalina.out log file as well as a bunch of other helpful logs under it's log directory.

> YourTomcatDir/logs/catalina.out

On openshift it's in

> jbossews/logs/catalina.out

Comment: I have looked for that file, but i did not find it, here is a list of the files: http://i.imgur.com/XZJsmgI.png

Comment: Updated answer, can you please verify?

Comment: no that directory dosnt exist, but i found the directory, it's at /app-root/logs